# paste two strings to achieve a desired combination

Tags: r, string, character, paste

I was wondering how to `paste()` `g` and `h` to obtain my `desired` combination shown below?

```
g <- c("compare","control")
h <- "Correlation"

paste0(h, g, collapse = "()") # Tried this with no success

desired <- "Correlation (compare,control)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
paste0(h, ' (', toString(g), ')')
#[1] "Correlation (compare, control)"
```

If you don't want the space in the comma then we can do it manually with `paste()`, i.e.

```
paste0(h, ' (', paste(g, collapse = ','), ')')
#[1] "Correlation (compare,control)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `glue`

```
library(stringr)
glue::glue("{h} ({str_c(g, collapse = ',')})")
Correlation (compare,control)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `paste`, you could try `sprintf` in a `do.call`. String `h` needs to be expanded by conversion specifications `%s`, though, by hand or `paste("Correlation", '(%s, %s)')`.

```
g <- c("compare", "control")
h <- "Correlation (%s, %s)"

do.call(sprintf, c(h, as.list(g)))
# [1] "Correlation (compare, control)"
```